# Multiple records recorded from a single page using django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is it possible and if so can someone point me in the right direction for this.  Here is my model.py:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField

class Task(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(
                               'Client',
                               )
    task_type = models.ForeginKey(
                                 'Task_Type',
                                  )
    date = models.DateTimeField()

class Task_Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField

class Task_Value(models.Model):
    value_num = models.DecimalField
    task = models.ForeignKey(
                             'Task',
                              )
```

What I want to do is have a form that the user sees as:

- Task Type  - Date  (applied to all the following records)
- 
- Client ID 1  -  Task Value 1
- Client ID 2  -  Task Value 2
- Client ID 3  -  Task Value 3
- Client ID 4  -  Task Value 4

Where a unique task record is created for every row that has valid values for client id, task type, and date.  And a second record is created (in Task_Value table) for every valid task value and a foreign key link the the task_type event created in the same row.

Is this possible from one page/table or do I need to do some type of a quick en masse entry for the task type and then load a form as a table with he events just created and record the values separately?  (This is for user entry, not admin entry)

---

So it would be something like formsets with a userdefined kwargs for the number of extras, but that share some common fields at the top that are not copied multiple times (so the user can create many records for the same date and task type).  Each of the two formsets would only have one repeated field (Client ID for the task record and the task_value for the task_value record.).  Then the second takes the pk from the first for the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Inline Formsets.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is Django's [*InlineModelAdmin Objects*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). They work quite nicely and there are several ways of setting them up.

Comment: I have never run across that before, thanks, good feather to have in my cap.  I improved my question some, but what I am looking for is a method for user entry, not admin.

Comment: @David__: So try looking at the admin code that implements the `InlineModelAdmin`. That's the nice thing about open source--you don't have to guess at how they did it. Look in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/`. There are 2 files: `stacked.html` and `tabular.html`. It's sort of the deep end of the pool in terms of template use and form use, but then that's where you are headed.